# Saving plots as image in R script

Tags: r

I am running the following R script on linux, which generate a plot for each dataset

```
data_root <- "home/data"
diff_dir <- c("C1.HSV_16H.NS.diff", "C1.HSV_8H.NS.diff")
png_root <- "/home/hgidnyc/Documents/"
library(cummeRbund)

for (d in diff_dir) {
    e <- paste(data_root, d, sep='/')
    cuff_data <- readCufflinks(e)

    # csDensity
    png_file <- paste(paste(png_root, d, sep='/'), 'csDensity.png', sep='.')
    png(png_file)   
    csDensity(cuff_data)
    dev.off();
}
```

It doesn't generate the png as I expected. However, as I copy and paste each line in the for loop individually in R console, it works.

Did I miss something?

Thanks

Comment: You can print png_file to screen to see if it has a prefix of ".", which turn it to a hidden file in Linux system.

Comment: the png_file seems to be normal

Comment: Does the `csDensity` use base graphics or grid graphics? Maybe try `print(csDensity(cuff_data))`